# (Chromium build) How can I generate Ninja project files for the third_party/webrtc/examples?

Tags: webrtc, chromium

I'm doing this on windows but I'm not sure it matters.  It appears that the command to generate the Ninja project files for the Chromium source tree:

```
gn gen out\Default
```

Only builds projects files for some of the code in `third_party\webrtc`.  I need to build project files for `third_party\webrtc\examples`. I've been trying to make changes to the `BUILD.gn` files but so far I haven't had any luck in getting gn to make me some project files for the examples.

Is there any switch or other flag I could set to build the examples?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to checkout webrtc and build run gn gen from there. The chromium build does not necessarily build all of the targets in webrtc.

See [the webrtc docs](https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/) for info on how to build.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I created a new directory and did a "fetch webrtc" instead of "fetch chromium" and did a build and the examples executables were built.  Thank you again!  I would upvote your answer but I don't have that ability.